# Configurable Swatches: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function provide() on null

Tags: magento-2.1.8, configurable-swatches

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function provide() on null in
>   /vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php:350

I'm using `Magento 2.1.8` with the `Ethan theme from MGS`. When I added swatches to configurable product and view the catalog this error appears and breaks the layout/styling of the page.

The single view page for the product doesn't load anything and display white screen.

I've looked all over for a solution, has anyone experienced this before?

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only able to fix this with a core hack.

Above:

`$swatchAttributes = $this->swatchAttributesProvider->provide($product);`

Put this:

`if (!isset($this->swatchAttributesProvider)) { $this->swatchAttributesProvider = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SwatchAttributesProvider::class); }`

Comment: It didn't work for me