# Magento 2 - PHP Error After Saving Any Attribute

Tags: magento2, error, swatches

I am working on a Magento 1 to 2 migration and, after migrating data from 1 to 2, I am receiving an error when attempting to save or create an attribute, and when attempting to load the category and product lists in the admin panel.

This is the error trace:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSwatchAttribute() on null in vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php:562
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/module-swatches/Model/Plugin/EavAttribute.php(97): Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data->isSwatchAttribute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor))
#1 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Swatches\Model\Plugin\EavAttribute->beforeBeforeSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor))
#2 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#3 generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor. in vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php on line 562
```

This is the function that's failing;

```
    public function isSwatchAttribute(Attribute $attribute)
    {
        return $this->swatchTypeChecker->isSwatchAttribute($attribute);
    }
```

I have removed `generated`, `var/cache`, `var/page_cache` and `var/view_preprocessed` manually, reset the indexers and ran them, re-run `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile` and reset permissions. Still getting this null so it's something with the M1 data, but I'm not sure what.

The version in use is 2.3.3 and I'm using MGS Claue for the theme. I've used this before without any trouble so I'm reasonably sure it's not the theme.

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193208/configurable-swatches-uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-provide-on-nu

Comment: I tried that with no effect.

Comment: Added this instead and it helped:
`if (!isset($this->swatchTypeChecker)) { $this->swatchTypeChecker = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SwatchAttributeType::class); }`

Comment: solve the issues ??

Comment: Solved these, yes. Had to do the above and one for the serializer. Seems to work fine now.

Comment: this link add in my answer and you accept and upvote the answer. ?? So becuse use the another commnity